# mpdf - how to prevent tables to be printed on new page, when to large

Tags: html, paging, mpdf, page-break

I'm using mpdf to generate a pdf with lots of tables from HTML. 
The structure is basically:

- Header
- H2
- Table
- H2
- Table
- H2
- Table

Some of the tables are large, too large (long!!!) to fill the page ,so they are printed on a complete new page instead of breaking the table into two parts! So I have lonely Headlines and some Pages busy with tables.

**Is there a way to force the tables to break it self instead of doing a pagebreak before they start?**

> My pages right now look like this:
>
> ---
>
> - H2
> - empty
> - empty
> - empty
>
> ---
>
> - Table
> - table
> - table
> - table
>
> ---
>
> - Table
> - table
> - H2
> - empty
>
> ---
>
> - Table
> - table
> - table
> - table
>
> and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

Autosize

If a table’s minimum width is too wide for the page/div/column, it will automatically reduce the font size in order to fit. The minimum width is calculated by the sum of column widths required to fit the longest single word in the column.

This function is ON by default, set in the config.php file as var $shrink_tables_to_fit = 1.4

The font size will only be reduced to a minimum size to avoid ridiculous results. The value of $shrink_tables_to_fit is the maximum factor by which the font-size will be reduced.

If it is turned off e.g. $mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 0; it is overridden by a specific declaration for a table e.g.:

or

A value of 1 will prevent any (unnecessary) resizing.